# How to use multiple reverse relationships from different content types in a single View Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, views

i have three content types

1- News

2- Articles

3- Press Releases

On every content type we have a custom field called 'industry'.

so when we create a news (or article or press release) we fill the industry field 'construction medical energy etc etc' (Means on which page[of content type industry] it should be display)

i want to create a view where i want to show all three content types "news ,articles, press releases" which have the field 'construction' in it.

Step by step Snap shots are attached for my views and content types.

1. adding news: http://prntscr.com/b940qh
2. my view screen shot: http://prntscr.com/b943oi
3. Want Result like : http://prntscr.com/b948qv

Answer (score 0):

Going of memory here, so things may not be exact.

One possible solution:

For **Contextual Filter** add Industry

**When Filter is not in the URL** select fixed value

**Type** select fixed

In the text box put `construction`

---

Another possible solution, if your Industry field is tax term reference field then add `Terms of the node` as a relationship. Then in Filter Criteria (below Fields), add tax terms and type your term name `construction`

Comment: Thanks @No Sssweat, but this didn't help. i cannot put the 'construction' keyword into any filter criteria because this is my post/node title of industry content type.

Comment: `this is my post/node title of industry content type` ??? I thought you said `On every content type we have a custom field called 'industry'.`...

Comment: i've custom content type "Industry", where i created content with title "Construction", then i created 'News (another custom content type)', while creating 'News' content i filled up the industry(node reference) field with "construction" http://prnt.sc/b940qh. Now into my view i am using field_industry_news as a relationship and aplying this relation on a contextual filter. Then into filter criteria i am selecting news,articles and press_release (3 content types). three because i want to add these 2 more content types along with news to display.(Now for single content type into CF its working)